# Django-Allauth: Optional fields in the signup form

Tags: django, django-allauth

I've working Django-Allauth setup with additional fields in my registration/signup form. With mandatory fields everything is OK, but my problems starts, when I'm trying to add some OPTIONAL fields to my registration form.

My settings.py:

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'myapp.forms.RegistrationForm'
```

forms.py:

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    category = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(), label="Password")
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(),
                            label="Password (again)"
                            )
    company = forms.CharField()

    ....
    class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', )

    def signup(self, request, user):
          category =  self.cleaned_data['category']
          company = self.cleaned_data['company']
          person = UserProfile(user=user, category=category, )
                         company=company,)
          person.save()
```

models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
...
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile',
                            verbose_name=_('user'))
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True,
                           verbose_name=_('company'))
User.profile = property(lambda u:     UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0]
```

So, the category field is mandatory, and it is OK. But how I can put the company field as an optional field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
company = forms.CharField(required=False)
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#required for more information.